# How can I install Windows 10 on my spare hard drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, installation, operating-systems, windows-installation

I want to install Windows 10 on a hard drive, I already have  Ubuntu 20 installed on my first hard drive and want to install Windows 10 on the second one. I did get Windows 10 on a USB though when I try to install it gives this error:

```
C:\Sources\install.vim not found
```

Though, if I look into the Sources directory there is a file names install.vim

Comment: _"I did get Windows 10 on a USB"_ - how?

Comment: @gronostaj I downloaded an ISO file from microsoft.com and used UNetBootin to burn it to the USB.

Comment: you might find the solution here:https://superuser.com/questions/1508503/how-to-avoid-windows-cannot-open-the-required-file-d-sources-install-wim-when

Answer (score 0):

The Windows ISO can't simply be written to a USB. ISOs have to be specially crafted to support it and Microsoft doesn't do that. You need a dedicated tool.

On Windows Rufus is the most reliable one. For Linux WoeUSB is available.

Comment: I used UNetBootin, but will re try with WoeUSB.

Comment: When I use WoeUSB it gives this error:
`Installation failed!
Exit code: 256
Log:
WoeUSB v3.3.1
==============================
Error: Target device is currently busy, unmount all mounted partitions in target device then try again
Target device is busy, please make sure you unmount all filesystems on target device or shutdown the computer before detaching it.
`
If I unmount the USB and unplug it then replug it, the same error.

Comment: If I try to do it with my USB unmounted it gives this error:

`Installation failed!
Exit code: 256
Log:
WoeUSB v3.3.1
==============================
Mounting source filesystem...
Wiping all existing partition table and filesystem signatures in /dev/sdb...
wipefs: error: /dev/sdb: probing initialization failed: No medium found
The command "wipefs --all "${target_device}"" failed with exit status "1", program is prematurely aborted
Unmounting and removing "/media/woeusb_source_1606997164_40607"...
You may now safely detach the target device
`

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it's not very reliable. I'd suggest creating it with Rufus on someone else's Windows PC.